# How to create session in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2

Hi i started learning ZF2 a week ago and i am facing some issues in how to work with session in ZF2.

```
namespace MyApplication\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\Session\Container; // We need this when using sessions

class UserController extends AbstractActionController {
    public function loginAction() {

        $user_session = new Container('user');
        $user_session->username = 'bravo';
}

    public function welcomeAction() {
        $user_session = new Container('user');
        $username = $user_session->username; // $username now contains 'bravo'
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me with the exact code snippet or tell me where i am wrong.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your code looks okay. Exactly how are you testing whether or not this works? Do you have any session configuration? Are you able to see whether sessions are being created?

Comment: What's the problem exactly?

Answer (score 1):

I am also not much familiar to ZF2 but my code may solve the issue you are facing.

```
class UserController extends AbstractActionController {
    public function loginAction() {
        // Store username in session
        $user_session = new Container('user');
        $user_session->username = 'bravo';

        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('welcome');
    }
```

The issue was in the function named loginAction you have not redirected after creating the session

Hope it helps you

Comment: This is not necessary.